# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails. MagicDraw tables error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, magic-draw

I have an assignment where I have to make tables in MagicDraw and then to  generate MySQL code. I pasted the generated code to SQL code section in phpMyAdmin and it showed an error:

SQL query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LogistikosCentras;
```

MySQL answer:

> #1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

These are my tables:

[image: Tables]

And this is some of my code:

```
CREATE TABLE LogistikosCentras
(
    pavadinimas varchar (255) NOT NULL,
    adresas varchar (255) NOT NULL,
    telefonas int NOT NULL,
    el_pastas varchar (255) NOT NULL,
    id_LogistikosCentras integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_LogistikosCentras)
);

CREATE TABLE SiuntosPervezimoTarnyba
(
    pavadinimas varchar (255) NOT NULL,
    transportoPriemonesTalpa double precision NOT NULL,
    transportoPriemoniuKiekis int NOT NULL,
    transportoPriemone varchar (15) NOT NULL,
    pristatymoGreitis varchar (8) NOT NULL,
    id_SiuntosPervezimoTarnyba integer NOT NULL,
    CHECK(transportoPriemone in ('sunkvezimis', 'laivas', 'lektuvas', 
'lengvojiMasina')),
    CHECK(pristatymoGreitis in ('valandos', 'dienos')),
    PRIMARY KEY(id_SiuntosPervezimoTarnyba)
);

CREATE TABLE Darbuotojas
(
    vardas varchar (255) NOT NULL,
    pavarde varchar (255) NOT NULL,
    tabelio_nr char (255) NOT NULL,
    pareigos char (10) NOT NULL,
    id_Darbuotojas integer NOT NULL,
    fk_LogistikosCentrasid_Logistikoscentras integer NOT NULL,
    CHECK(pareigos in ('buhalteris', 'krovejas')),
    PRIMARY KEY(id_Darbuotojas, fk_LogistikosCentrasid_Logistikoscentras),
    CONSTRAINT dirba FOREIGN KEY(fk_LogistikosCentrasid_Logistikoscentras) 
REFERENCES LogistikosCentras (id_LogistikosCentras)
);
```

Comment: Welcome. MySQL is telling you the issue, you will need to remove the foreign key constraint in table `Darbuotojas` before attempting to drop `LogistikosCentras`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/constraint-foreign-key.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't drop a MySQL table due to foreign key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851989/cant-drop-a-mysql-table-due-to-foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: Thank you for helping. I just reversed the order of the requests to delete tables and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reversed the order of the requests to delete tables and it worked.