# Dropping a constraint with foreign key on POPSQL

Tags: mysql

I have tried to drop the employee table that I created but was unable to due to the constraints of the foreign key. when I drop the employee I get this error (Cannot drop table 'employee' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'branch_ibfk_1' on table 'branch')

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(40),
  last_name VARCHAR(40),
  birth_day DATE,
  sex VARCHAR(1),
  salary INT,
  super_id INT,
  branch_id INT
);


ALTER TABLE employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY(branch_id)
REFERENCES branch(branch_id)
ON DELETE SET NULL;

ALTER TABLE employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY(super_id)
REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
ON DELETE SET NULL;

CREATE TABLE branch (
  branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  branch_name VARCHAR(40),
  mgr_id INT,
  mgr_start_date DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY(mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't drop a MySQL table due to foreign key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851989/cant-drop-a-mysql-table-due-to-foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: You Can not delete parent table witch have child table before deleting all childs.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

Drop table branch;

Drop table employee;

Comment: I tried that it did not work. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE Branch DROP CONSTRAINT branch_ibfk_1;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).